# Java datatype that is symmetric pair?

Tags: java, tuples

I would like to pre-calculate a similarity score of a group of elements.
So if the group has three elements, A, B, C, then there are scores for similarity:
A,B: score1
A,C: score2
B,C: score3
C,B: score3

The relationship is symmetric, so f(B,A) is the same as f(A,B).  I would like to do something like: HashMap<Pair<>, Score>, but so far of the tuple classes I have looked at, f(B,A).equals(f(A,B)) does not hold.

Is there a Pair tuples implementation where Pair(A,B) == Pair(B,A)?

Comment: What's stopping your from writing your own Tuple with your own definition of what `equals` means? That method is one line of code. The `hashCode` method that you need to use it as your `Map`'s key should be equally easy to write.

Comment: How about representing your tuple as a set of two elements?

Comment: I am currently writing my own implementation, but after thinking about it, I thought someone else would have a library that does this.  I just don't like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: To ask for a library, use [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow. Explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: By the way, a couple of tips: (a) You can override `equals`/`hashCode` on a [`record`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395), and implement `Comparable` there too. (b) Check *Google Guava* and *Eclipse Collections* for something that might do what you want (I've no idea if they do).

Answer (score 4):

As suggested, if you really wanted to you could use a `Set`, but much nicer to write your own, especially if you need to preserve the order of your two elements.

```java
public class Eg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> ab = new LinkedHashSet<String>(List.of("A", "B"));
        Set<String> ba = new LinkedHashSet<String>(List.of("B", "A"));

        System.out.println(ab.equals(ba));
        System.out.println(ba.equals(ab));
        System.out.println(ab.stream().findFirst().get());
        System.out.println(ab.stream().skip(1).findFirst().get());
        System.out.println(ba.stream().findFirst().get());
        System.out.println(ba.stream().skip(1).findFirst().get());

        MyTuple<String> mab = new MyTuple<>("A", "B");
        MyTuple<String> mba = new MyTuple<>("B", "A");
        System.out.println(mab.equals(mba));
        System.out.println(mba.equals(mab));
    }

    public record MyTuple<T>(T first, T second) {
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return o instanceof MyTuple<?> other &&
                    ((other.first.equals(first) && other.second.equals(second)) ||
                            (other.first.equals(second) && other.second.equals(first)));
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(first, second);
        }
    }
}
```